# storing the downloaded pdf files in document directories and retrieving

Tags: ios, pdf

here am creating the download task

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://app.msf.gov.sg/Portals/0/Summary/assistance/CSSD/ComCare%20@%20a%20Glance%20-%20English%20(final).pdf"]];
    [downloadTask resume];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

and here am dowloading the pdf file successfully

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.progressView setHidden:YES];

    });
}
```

Now my question is that how can i store that pdf file and retrieve again
please help me
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Just move file from 'location' to your document directory:

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSURL *docFolder = [[fileManager URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] firstObject];
NSURL *fileURL = [docFolder URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.pdf" isDirectory:NO];
[fileManager moveItemAtURL: location toURL:fileURL error:nil];

NSLog(@" pdf file is here %@", fileURL);
```

Answer (score 0):

- We have to copy the location to our documents directory

  ```
  NSError *error;

  NSString *fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest.URL.lastPathComponent;

  NSArray *docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *loc = [docDir objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *filePathName = [loc stringByAppendingString:fileName];

  NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  if ([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:filePathName]) {
      [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:filePathName error:&error];
  }

  BOOL success =  [fileMgr copyItemAtPath:[location path] toPath:filePathName error:&error];
  if (success) {
      NSLog(@"FIle is successfully copied to documents directory");
  }else{
      NSLog(@"error:%@",error.description);
  }
  ```